# Regexp_like in oracle , to extract a sting from input

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a input like

```
 10-Mar-2024 11:00:23 AM,234

Param=10-Mar-2024 11:00:23 AM,234
```

I need to extract date and the value after the comma  in oracle.

Kindly help

I need to extract the date and value from the input string.

Need to extract the value before comma and after comma

Comment: try https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/split-comma-separated-values-into-rows-in-oracle-database

Comment: `SUBSTR(param, 1, INSTR(param, ',') - 1)` and `SUBSTR(param, INSTR(param, ',') + 1)`